# Integral on manifold with orientation given by vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, tangent-bundle

I have task described below. I'm not sure if I started correctly and how to finish (include orientation to calculations). Could you check it and give me some explanations?

> Let $S = \lbrace (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1, x+y+z=0, x\geq0 \rbrace$,
>   find $p \in S$ such that vector $v = (1, -1, 0)$ is tangent
>   at the point $p$.
>
> Let $\omega = x~dy - y~dz$. Calculate $\int_S \omega$,
>   where orientation is given by $v$ at the $p$.

$v$ have to be orthogonal to $\{x^2+y^2+z^2\}$ and $\{x+y+z=0\}$. It's not hard to show that $p = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}, \frac{-2}{\sqrt{6}}) \in S$ is our point.

Then I tried to find parametrization. $z = - (x+y) \Rightarrow 2(x^2 + y^2 + xy) = 1$, now looking at $y$ as parameter:

$$
x^2 + yx + (y^2-\frac{1}{2}) = 0\\
\Delta = y^2-4(y^2-\frac{1}{2})=2-3y^2 \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow\\
\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \geq |y|\\
x = \frac{-y + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2} ~~~~ \because x \geq 0\\
y \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} ~~~~ \because x \geq 0\\
y \in \left[ -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right] =A'\\
A = \text{int} A'
$$
So I made parametrization (we removed only two extreme points - measure 0)
$$
\psi(t) = \left( \frac{-y + \sqrt{2-3y^2}}{2}, y, - \frac{y + \sqrt{2-3y^2}}{2}\right)
$$

And now forgetting about orientation, we can calculate
$$
\int_S \omega = \int_A \frac{-y + \sqrt{2-3y^2}}{2} \cdot 1 - y \cdot \left(-\frac{1 - \frac{3y}{\sqrt{2-3y^2}}}{2}\right)~dy=\\
\frac{1}{2}\int_A (\sqrt{2-3y^2} - y) + y - \frac{3y^2}{\sqrt{2-3y^2}}~dy =\\
\frac{1}{2}\int_A \frac{2-3y^2}{\sqrt{2-3y^2}} - \frac{3y^2}{\sqrt{2-3y^2}} = \frac{1}{2} \int_A \frac{2-6y^2}{\sqrt{2-3y^2}}\\
= \frac{1}{4}
$$

And how should I include information about orientation now, when given is vector $v$ at point $p$? I understand what orientation is (as one of two class of abstraction). When two parametrization has same orientation. Why I can check only at one point. Etc. I know some imagination methods like "if you are walking..." (I saw MIT lectures and I have to say that my imagination is very poor).

So, how can I check it algorithmically? Without using imagination, only with calculations.
I will be very grateful for general answer for any manifold ($m$-dimentional in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and example on $S$ from given task.